# Finding smallest (or largest) k elements in a given balanced binary search tree

Tags: performance, algorithm, binary-search-tree

Given a balanced binary search tree with integer nodes, I need to write an algorithm to find the smallest k elements and store them in a linked list or array. The tricky part is, it is required such algorithm runs in O(k+log(n)), where n is the number of elements in the tree. I only have an algorithm that runs O(k*log(n)), which uses the rank function. So my question is how to achieve the required performance?

I've written a code doing such algorithm but I don't know if it is running at O(k+log(n)):

(The size function is the number of nodes with the given subtree.)

```
// find k smallest elements in the tree
public Iterable<Key> kSmallest(int k) {
    LinkedList<Key> keys = new LinkedList<Key>();
    kSmallest(k, root, keys);
    return keys;
}

// find k smallest elements in the subtree given by node and add them to keys
private void kSmallest(int k, Node node, LinkedList<Key> keys) {
    if (k <= 0 || node == null) return;
    if (node.left != null) {
        if (size(node.left) >= k) kSmallest(k, node.left, keys);
        else {
            keys.add(node.key);
            kSmallest(k - 1, node.left, keys);
            kSmallest(k - 1 - size(node.left), node.right, keys);
        }
    }
    else {
        keys.add(node.key);
        kSmallest(k - 1, node.right, keys);
    }
}
```

Comment: Conduct an in-order traversal of the tree and stop when you have traversed k nodes.

Comment: traversing would take O(k) time but if you are constructing the binary tree too then it would take O(n*log(n)+k) time. Cant help you there..

Comment: Traversing takes O(log n + k) time if you start at the root, since there's log(n) steps before you find the first element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have to to a inorder traversal and stop when you have gone through k nodes.
this would run in O(k+log(n)) time.

code:

```
int k = nodesRequired;
int A[] = new int[k];
int number_of_nodes=0;
void traverse_tree(tree *l){
    if (number_of_nodes<k) {
        traverse_tree(l->left);
        process_item(l->item);
        traverse_tree(l->right);
    }
 }

 void process_item(item){
     A.push(item);
     ++number_of_nodes;
 }
```

Comment: I have a prototype that works, but don't know its performance. Can you analyze it?

Comment: This takes O(log n + k) time, since there's O(log n) steps before the first item is processed. There's also a bug (`==k` should be `<k`).

Comment: @Anonymous, thanks, you mean >=k? I think it is correct since all testing outputs are correct.

Comment: @Anonymous thanks for the correction made the changes.

Comment: Can you help me understand the time complexity analysis? It takes O(k) time to initialize array A and O(logn) time to identify the minimum value of the BST. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to account for the time to needed to identify and push the remaining k-1 elements to A.

Comment: if the root's right subtree contains more than `k` elements, then won't this algorithm wrongly process the root?